# How to change the font size in ListView in JavaFX?

Tags: listview, javafx

I tried this suggestion http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5421037 but style cannot be found.

Is there any other way?

Lots of thanks,
cancelledout

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on the version of JavaFX, I will suppose it is about 1.3.
By default, `ListView` shows the result of `toString()` applied to the objects stored in its `items` variable.
But you can define a `cellFactory` function that will generate a `ListCell` that takes these objects and presents in a `Node` holding whatever you put in, for example a `Text` or `Label`, or something more complex. So, there, you can format the text the usual way.

Now, if you don't want to go to that level of detail, just use CSS:

```
.list-cell 
{
  -fx-font: 18pt "Arial";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, direct approach:

```
ListView listView=new ListView();
        if(!listView.getItems().isEmpty())
        {
            VirtualFlow ch=(VirtualFlow) listView.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(0);
            Font anyfont=new Font("Tahoma",16);
            for (int i = 0; i < ch.getCellCount(); i++)
            {
                Cell cell= ch.getCell(i);
                cell.setFont(anyfont);
            }
        }
```