# Change ListView font size in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I want to know how can I change the list view items text font size in JavaFx. The size of each row text will vary . I tried using cell factor property but i don't know how to use it. Can anybody help me here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A similar question is here:

[How to change the font size in ListView in JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117086/how-to-change-the-font-size-in-listview-in-javafx)

Also you can play with the `.css` below:

```
.list-cell:filled:selected:focused, .list-cell:filled:selected {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(#328BDB 0.0%, #207BCF 25.0%, #1973C9 75.0%, #0A65BF 100.0%);
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.list-cell{
    -fx-font-size:15.0;
}

.list-cell:even { /* <=== changed to even */
    -fx-background-color: white;
}

.list-cell:filled:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #0093ff;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
```

> How to use external css in JavaFX?

[How to use external css file to style a javafx application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066799/how-to-use-external-css-file-to-style-a-javafx-application)

> How to programmatically change the size of text?:

**Before Java8:**

```
listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
            @Override
            public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> p) {
                return new ListCell<String>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (item != null) {
                            setText(item);

                            // decide to add a new styleClass
                            // getStyleClass().add("costume style");
                            // decide the new font size
                            setFont(Font.font(16));
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        });
```

**With lambda expressions:**

```
listView.setCellFactory(cell -> {
            return new ListCell<String>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (item != null) {
                        setText(item);

                        // decide to add a new styleClass
                        // getStyleClass().add("costume style");
                        // decide the new font size
                        setFont(Font.font(16));
                    }
                }
            };
        });
```

Comment: Yeah i saw that but these font size are fix . I want it variable . Size of each row can change any time

Comment: @ahmad faraz I edited the question let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Store text and text size in a item class

```
public class SizedText {

    private final int textSize;
    private final String text;

    public SizedText(int textSize, String text) {
        this.textSize = textSize;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public int getTextSize() {
        return textSize;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

And use a `cellFactory` that returns `ListCell`s that set the text size according to the item data in the `updateItem` method.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ListView<SizedText> list = new ListView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new SizedText(10, "10"),
            new SizedText(15, "15"),
            new SizedText(20, "20"),
            new SizedText(25, "25"),
            new SizedText(30, "30"),
            new SizedText(35, "35"),
            new SizedText(40, "40"),
            new SizedText(50, "50"),
            new SizedText(60, "60")
    ));

    list.setCellFactory(l -> new ListCell<SizedText>() {

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(SizedText item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty || item == null) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(item.getText());
                setFont(Font.font(item.getTextSize()));
            }
        }

    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(list);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In javaFx you can use css to style different objects. It depends on the object in your list view but it would go something like this.

```
ListView<Hyperlink> listview = ..

            ObservableList<Hyperlink> lists = listview.getItems();

            for(Hyperlink link:lists)
            {
                link.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#ffffff");
            }
```

Comment: @ahmadfaraz  Strings are not a javafx object. I would use Label to represent a String

Answer (score -1):

For anyone struggling to make sense of fabians example above, I thought it would help to break it down and show it in a simpler context. It works quite well and lets you set the font programmatically instead of needing to use CSS.

```
ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();

listView.setCellFactory(l->new ListCell<String>() {
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if(empty || item == null) {
            setText(null);
        }
        else {
            setText(item.toString());
            setFont(Fonts.Monaco(15));
        }
    }
});
```

You can do this with any class you want, as long as it has a method for getting a String from it that will end up in the cell via the setText method. Like for example, if you make your own class, then just write an Override method for toString() and make sure that method spits out the test you need to show up in the list. Everywhere you see String in this example, if you use another class make sure that class is declared in all of those three spots.

Once you set the cell factory you can add or remove from the ListView as much as you want and it just works.

In this example, the Fonts class is my own that I made that lets me easily gain access to different fonts, but you could just as easily use `javafx.scene.text.Font.loadFont()`.

So if I wanted to use a custom class

```
class MyClass {
    public MyClass(String text, int num) {
        this.text = text;
        this.num  = num;
    }

    private final String text;
    private final int    num;

    public String getMyText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

I could implement it into the ListView like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    public static void makeListView() {
        ListView<MyClass> list = new ListView();
        listView.setCellFactory(l->new ListCell<MyClass>() {
            protected void updateItem(MyClass item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if(empty || item == null) {
                    setText(null);
                }
                else {
                    setText(item.getMyText());
                    setFont(Font.loadFont("Courier New",15));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

From there, you could drop as many instantiations of MyClasss into the list as you need and it will be added using the font you spec in
the setFont() method.